# How would I make a menu scrollable in Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I can not get this to scroll. I have tried all the conventional ways, scrollable in code, change the layout to scroll and no luck tells me child view can not work.
Here is my code snippit that I am trying to get to scroll:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bk1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item1btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="item1"
        android:text="@string/item1btn"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item2btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:onClick="item2"
        android:text="@string/item2btn"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item3btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:onClick="item3"
        android:text="@string/item3btn"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/item4btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:onClick="item4"
        android:text="@string/item4btn"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/item5btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:onClick="item5"
        android:text="@string/item5btn"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item6btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:onClick="item6"
        android:text="@string/item6btn"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item7btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:onClick="item7"
        android:text="@string/item7btn"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bk1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item1btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="item1"
        android:text="@string/item1btn"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item2btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:onClick="item2"
        android:text="@string/item2btn"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item3btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:onClick="item3"
        android:text="@string/item3btn"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/item4btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:onClick="item4"
        android:text="@string/item4btn"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/item5btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:onClick="item5"
        android:text="@string/item5btn"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item6btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:onClick="item6"
        android:text="@string/item6btn"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item7btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:onClick="item7"
        android:text="@string/item7btn"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I just added a `scrollview` and a child `linearlayout` and your things inside it.

Comment: Thanks, I could have sworn I tried that before but I guess I did not. Yes it works for me .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use ScrollView like this?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background1"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bk1"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/item1btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="item1"
    android:text="@string/item1btn"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/item2btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:onClick="item2"
    android:text="@string/item2btn"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/item3btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:onClick="item3"
    android:text="@string/item3btn"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<Button
  android:id="@+id/item4btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:onClick="item4"
    android:text="@string/item4btn"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<Button
  android:id="@+id/item5btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:onClick="item5"
    android:text="@string/item5btn"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/item6btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:onClick="item6"
    android:text="@string/item6btn"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/item7btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:onClick="item7"
    android:text="@string/item7btn"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I could have sworn I tried that before but got no results. Again thanks a million.